# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi every body i have big problem and i don’t know how to fix it, after i update my php to 7.4 i got these errors,what i can i do? Please help me

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/class-elementor.php on line 45

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/class-elementor.php on line 68

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/class-translate.php on line 15

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/class-translate.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/lib/fonts.php on line 4

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/lib/icon-control.php on line 11

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/lib/icon.php on line 4

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/includes/lib/localization.php on line 3

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home2/honarpa1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/persian-elementor/inc/persian-elementor-templates.php on line
```

Comment: there are some changes updating to 7.4 - you may want to check if Elementor is ready for it yet first and then change the version. For now in Production you may want to use 7.3 until you can be sure all of your used plugins and themes are ready for php74

Comment: Dear Mr Prosalov, Is it possible to return back to the version 7.3? And my another question is what can cause the error trying to access... happend?

Comment: And how can be sure all of used plugins and theme are ready for upper php version?

Comment: the only way to be certain on that is to check for related dev notes and/or test it on some dev environment.